# Issue with json parsing php

Tags: php, json, api, parsing

I'm currently trying to tie my php application to the Pocket app api using the http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve route. The connection itself is fine and i can get the returned json. The json returned is as per below:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "complete": 1,
    "list": {
        "446599840": {
            "item_id": "446599840",
            "resolved_id": "446599840",
            "given_url": "http://www.theguardian.com/media-network/media-network-blog/2013/jan/07/panasonic-changing-consumer-retail-technology",
            "given_title": "The changing consumer-retailer relationship: interview with Panasonic | Med",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1395140204",
            "time_updated": "1395140204",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 6,
            "resolved_title": "Guardian Professional",
            "resolved_url": "http://www.theguardian.com/media-network/media-network-blog/2013/jan/07/panasonic-changing-consumer-retail-technology",
            "excerpt": "Time to give call centres a facelift? Businesses have an opportunity to reinvent their customer-service by applying new technologies in the right areas, says Simon Parkinson. Photograph: 13/Ocean/Corbis",
            "is_article": "0",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "1",
            "word_count": "0"
        },
        "482104798": {
            "item_id": "482104798",
            "resolved_id": "482104798",
            "given_url": "http://www.theintegratedretailer.com/news/795/retailers-urged-to-embrace-techno…o-create-knowledge-sharing-high-performing-and-highly-engaged-workforces/",
            "given_title": "Retailers urged to embrace technology to create knowledge sharing, high per",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1395144267",
            "time_updated": "1395146556",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 3,
            "resolved_title": "Retailers urged to embrace technology to create knowledge sharing, high performing and highly engaged workforces",
            "resolved_url": "http://www.theintegratedretailer.com/news/795/retailers-urged-to-embrace-techno…o-create-knowledge-sharing-high-performing-and-highly-engaged-workforces/",
            "excerpt": "With evidence suggesting that businesses that achieve high levels of sustainable employee engagement average an operating margin close to three times higher than those with high traditional engagement, large retailers are being urged to explore the potential that new technology can play in improv",
            "is_article": "1",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "1",
            "word_count": "502"
        },
        "571816084": {
            "item_id": "571816084",
            "resolved_id": "571816084",
            "given_url": "http://www.hrreview.co.uk/supplier-news/supplier-training-development/british-sme-lights-the-fuse-for-free-online-education-anywhere-in-the-world/50353",
            "given_title": "British SME lights the Fuse for free online education anywhere in the world",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1395144314",
            "time_updated": "1395144314",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 0,
            "resolved_title": "British SME lights the Fuse for free online education anywhere in the world",
            "resolved_url": "http://www.hrreview.co.uk/supplier-news/supplier-training-development/british-sme-lights-the-fuse-for-free-online-education-anywhere-in-the-world/50353",
            "excerpt": "A British SME, which has developed an online learning platform for some of the UK’s leading retailers, will demonstrate how commercial organisations implementing its technology are simultaneously supporting the social goal of delivering free secondary education content to any student anywhere in",
            "is_article": "1",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "1",
            "word_count": "429"
        },
        "571816595": {
            "item_id": "571816595",
            "resolved_id": "0",
            "given_url": "http://www.hrreview.co.uk/supplier-news/supplier-hr-strategy-practice/organisations-can-now-create-their-own-online-central-knowledge-bank/50085",
            "given_title": "Organisations can now create their own online central knowledge bank",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1395144298",
            "time_updated": "1395144298",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 1
        },
        "571820367": {
            "item_id": "571820367",
            "resolved_id": "571820367",
            "given_url": "http://www.palife.co.uk/surveys-current-affairs/item/489-and-finally-something-for-the-boss",
            "given_title": "And finally... something for the boss",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1395144281",
            "time_updated": "1395144281",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 2,
            "resolved_title": "And finally... something for the boss",
            "resolved_url": "http://www.palife.co.uk/surveys-current-affairs/item/489-and-finally-something-for-the-boss",
            "excerpt": "At PA Life we're devoted to bringing you the very latest news, tips, advice and recommendations on a whole smorgasbord of topics that we hope are of interest to you in your professional lives.",
            "is_article": "1",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "1",
            "word_count": "310"
        },
        "571822317": {
            "item_id": "571822317",
            "resolved_id": "299897045",
            "given_url": "http://www.learningsolutionsmag.com/articles/1004/?utm_campaign=lsmag&utm_medium=some&utm_source=linkedin&goback=.gde_1821266_member_160113156",
            "given_title": "EMEA Reporter: African Virtual School is Model for World by Nic Laycock : L",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1395140611",
            "time_updated": "1395140611",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 4,
            "resolved_title": "EMEA Reporter: African Virtual School is Model for World",
            "resolved_url": "http://www.learningsolutionsmag.com/articles/1004/",
            "excerpt": "What do you do when you have to serve out an employment restraint (a non-compete clause)? Go and found a social impact company, of course, using your income from your previous employment!",
            "is_article": "1",
            "is_index": "0",
            "has_video": "0",
            "has_image": "0",
            "word_count": "774"
        },
        "571823356": {
            "item_id": "571823356",
            "resolved_id": "0",
            "given_url": "http://uk.prweb.com/releases/2010/12/prweb4870124.htm",
            "given_title": "Fusion Universal Wins Coveted E-Learning Award Using Panviva's SupportPoint",
            "favorite": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "time_added": "1395140303",
            "time_updated": "1395140304",
            "time_read": "0",
            "time_favorited": "0",
            "sort_id": 5
        }
    },
    "since": 1396516912
}
```

However the issue is that i can't seem to parse this effectively. There doesn't seem to be an entry point for the overall array ('list' fails). I think the numeric entries for each are also causing an issue for me. Essentially i'm trying to loop through then items to pull the associated data i.e. 'given_title' for each entry but no matter which method of parsing i can't seem to get a result.

I'm currently using this format in the php (obviously wrong):

```
<?php
foreach ($result['list'] as $item){
 echo "Item: ", $item['item_id'];
}
var_dump(json_decode($result,true));
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `$array = json_decode($result, true); foreach ($array['list'] as ...)`...?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert the json data to an array.

The "true" parameter makes sure that it returns an associative array instead of an object.
The pre tag is for formatting.

```
$result = json_decode($json, true);
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($result["list"] as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi @Whitebird - i had already tried with the json decode and i know that's what i need however doing it this way generated the following errors which perhaps i should have also showed in the question: Warning:  'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' and 'uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '446599840' of undefined' which is where i think the issue with the numerical values is coming in.

Comment: This is my whole code which I used for testing, can you tell me the difference? http://pastebin.com/05H2Lx76

Comment: It's quite strange as if i use your code from pastebin and have the json in-file this seems to work. However i'm pulling this json via an authenticated Pocket api request and when i switch back to that this is where it seems to fall down currently as before. I think i need to take a further look at that side of the equation being as i can get your pastebin working with the json in-line. By your original answer how would i print the item id's for each.

Comment: No problem, i've got it - print_r($value['item_id']);

Answer (score 0):

fist, you need to convert json data to array:

```
$result=json_decode($result);

foreach ($result['list'] as $item){
 echo "Item: ", $item['item_id'];
}
```